# Transferring Interpolated Results to Line Features

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, symbology, cartography, network

I am using ArcDesktop 10.3.  I have a road network feature dataset and a point city feature class. Using Network Analyst and Closest Facility along with several incident points, I solved several routes for distances to the incidents. I then joined the distance from facility to the incident to the incident.  I then used IDW to interpolate travel distance to all areas on my map.

I like how it looks, but I had an idea to transfer the color of the travel time (the light to dark blue in the map) not on the country, but rather on the road (line) itself.  So the road as it leaves one of the "facility" cities, it will start as light and become darker the further along in distance it goes.

I thought I would join the raster value I created in the IDW to the line, but I can't seem to do this.  How would one go about accomplishing this task?

[image]

Comment: Split roads in segments, interpolate shapes and use add Z information to 3d shapes

Comment: that will only work for the segments that are actual routes i think,  not all the segments are solved for because some roads dont have incidents (cities) at the end of them.  I guess I could always add more cities so all road segments are solved for.  Any other ways?